# How to execute javascript in DataItemTemplateContent on gridview paging

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

I've got a DevExpress GridView which contains a column with a custom DataItemTemplate

```
column.SetDataItemTemplateContent( c =>
  {
    ViewContext.Writer.Write(
      Html.Partial( "PartialView" )
    );
} );
```

with the partial view `PartialView` looking like:

```
<p>text</p>

<script>
  console.log("hello from PartialView");
</script>
```

So, after page reload I get the `console.log` output x times, where x is the number of rows displayed in my GridView. But if I go to the next page in the GridView the js doesn't get executed anymore and I don't get any more `console.log` outputs. The partial view is rendered correctly as there is still "text" getting displayed for every row.

Any ideas how to get the output again during use of gridview pagination?

(btw. my goal is to render a chemical structure via javascript The example is simplified to show the general problem.)

Comment: I think the second "page" will not execute this JavaScript because it is not a "full page load". I do not understand your goal. However, if you are attempting to run some js after the view is "rendered" - I would recommend that you execute a js function as call back from your partial post. This way you can iterate through your object right after your partial post has finished on the client side.

Comment: My goal is to render a chemical structure via javascript into every row. The example is simplified to show the general problem.

Comment: Interesting. I am guessing you have a "next page" or "2" link that you click on to indicate that you intend to execute the next page query. Is this functionality built into the control? Or are you executing some custom js to do an HTTP POST to get your partial view back? I think the problem is that when this post happens you are not getting a "full HTML page" back, therefore any js in the return will not get "evaluated". So you need to work around this "issue". I believe the work around is to use "callbacks" or function references.

Comment: If you have access to the product documentation, you can check if this product's partial post library allows you to put your own hooks in it.

Comment: I use the built-in pager from the GridViewExtension. The only controller action involved here is the callback action which is used by the gridview for every round-trip (e.g. paging, column changes, filter updates etc.). So my grid implementation looks quite exactly like here (besides the SetDataItemTemplateContent part): http://mvc.devexpress.com/GridView/Paging

Comment: I already tried to use the EndCallback event fired from gridview to trigger the js, but sadly the EndCallback event is fired too early (directly after callback is finished and before page layout begins).

Comment: Does the GridView control have any client side events like here - http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_ClientSideEventstopic. You could use an "init" type event or something similar.

Comment: Yes it has, but none of those fires at the right time (see my comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952690/how-to-execute-javascript-in-dataitemtemplatecontent-on-gridview-paging#comment19244114_13952690)) and "Init" only fires once the control is initialized.

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress Support directly?

Comment: Same reason as with my last question ;-)

Comment: did you see error window and confirmed that there were no error??

Comment: Yes, there was no error.

Answer (score 0):

Try add to script tag id that start with "dxss_", like this:

```
<script id="dxss_myscript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('hello from PartialView');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but instead of embedding javascript in the return, there are client side scripts you can connect to.  I would give your DOM elements a unique class and then set the ClientSideEvents.EndCallBack.

```
settings.ClientSideEvents.EndCallback = 
  "function (s,e) { if (e.command != 'FUNCTION') { YourCustomMethod(s, e) }; }";
```

some simple jquery or straight javascript would allow you to get a list of the DOM objects matching your class name as a selector, and you can include any additional data you need for your processing in data properties.

In your example, you're partial view would look something like:

```
<p class="actonme" data-msg="hello from PartialView">text</p>
```

and your method would look something like:

```
function YourCustomMethod(s, e) {
    var objs = document.getElementsByClassName('actonme');
    var count = objs.length;
    for (var iIndex = 0; iIndex < count; iIndex++) {
        console.log(objs[iIndex].getAttribute("data-msg"));
    }
}
```

Comment: There may be plenty of syntax errors in this code, I typed it off the top of my head, but the idea should be enough to work with. You can also just pass your method name instead of the javascript as the value of ClientSideEvents.EndCallback.  but I wanted to clearly illustrate the variables that are passed as object (s, the reference to the object and e, the event arguments)